# Jquery inline DatePicker Error when selecting a date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Cannot figure out what is wrong with this code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
                .datepicker('setDate', '13-10-13');

$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(this).val();
        alert ('setting date');
        document.procedureform.proceduredate.value = date;
    }
});
```

If I remove:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'})
                .datepicker('setDate', '13-10-13');
```

I can select a date just fine and it alerts me.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect date format for what you are specifying for the datepicker in 'setDate'. It should be '2013-10-13'. ('yy' represents a four digit year):

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Also if you want '2013-10-13' to be the default date use this syntax:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
          defaultDate: '2013-10-13' 
 });
```

See defaultDate options here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate